# Send message through websocket to specific users

Tags: javascript, spring, websocket

I have a Java application built by Spring Boot, and a simple application run on browser by JavaScript .

I can broadcast message to all users, and now I want to send message to different users according to their identities, but there's some problems.

I'm a newbie about websocket and Javascript, I've searched for plenty articles, but still can't figure out where the problem is.

Can someone give me a hint? Very appreciate!

The way I used to send to specific users is

```
messageTemplate.convertAndSend()
```

And here is my Java code :

```
@Controller
public class GreetingWSController {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate messageTemplate;

    public GreetingWSController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.messageTemplate = template;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/login")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public GreetingWS login(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        if (...) {
            System.out.println("A player has logged in.");
            return new GreetingWS("Welcome! You are the " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(order.toString()) + "th user.");
        } else {
            return start();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        messageTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "Let's play!");
    }
}
```

And Websocket config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket");
    }
}
```

My browser can receive the `GreetingWS` object returned inside the `if` section, but can't receive the message sent by

```
messageTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "Let's play!");
```

in `start` function.

Here is my Javascript code :

```
const stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket'
});

stompClient.onConnect = (frame) => {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', (greeting) => {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
};

function setConnected(connected) {
    $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
    if (connected) {
        $("#conversation").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#conversation").hide();
    }
    $("#greetings").html("");
}

function connect() {
    stompClient.activate();
}

function showGreeting(message) {
    $("#greetings").append("<tr><td>" + message + "</td></tr>");
}

$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault());
    $( "#connect" ).click(() => connect());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message to specific users according to their session id, you should use  `SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser()` instead of `SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend()`